# how to refer to the global namespace

Tags: c++

Inside a method `isGood` I want to use function `isGood` from the global namespace. How do I avoid to have `isGood` interpreted as the same method instead of the global function ?

```
bool isGood(){ return_if_it_is_good;}

class X{
int a;
bool isGood(){return isGood(a);}
}
```

Comment: Add scope resolution operator `::`

Comment: Use the scope operator : `::isGodd(a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call with the `::` operator :

```
bool isGood(){ return_if_it_is_good;}

class X{
int a;
bool isGood(){return ::isGood(a);}
}
```